# Connector for load cell

Tags: connector, load-cell

I'm working on a scale that uses a tin-plated connector between the load cell and the PCB where the ADC is mounted. The connector is JST ZH (4pins) tin-plated.

During testing of this design, I have seen that some of the load cells start to show some deviation over time (months). Sometimes I can reset the error by knocking on the load cell enclosure, and by knocking even more I can reproduce the error. The load cell enclosure is not air-sealed, and the connector is subjected to whatever humidity of the surrounding air.

I've isolated the issue to be a contact problem in the connector. After opening the load cell enclosure and slightly moving the connector the problem can't be reproduced anymore and I think that this is because the oxide layer is disrupted when moving the connector.

For mass manufacturing, I'm looking for a more reliable connection between the load cell and the PCB and I wonder if I need to solder the wires to the PCB? This will be a more time-consuming step during assembly. Or would a connector with gold-plated pins solve the problem?

Comment: What environment? These connectors are quite rugged and using them in an indoors environment will not be a problem. You shouldn't need to worry about oxidation then. Are you using the crimp parts or IDC parts on the wire? The wire connector (especially the crimp version) might fail over time if someone has a habit of incorrectly removing the contact by pulling on the wires, rather than carefully removing it by separating the plastic housings with a screwdriver etc.

Comment: For outdoors environments you should be using gold plated connectors, obviously. You need to clarify where the product is used.

Comment: It is designed for indoor use, however, I assume that some users will be using it outside as well. The connectors I currently use are crimped on the wires.

Comment: These (any) connectors will _not_ oxidate after a few months of indoor use. Either you are doing something very strange with the product or the problem is elsewhere. As mentioned, maybe damaged crimps because someone is pulling at the wires. Or cold solder joints somewhere.

Comment: We encountered problems like this with non gold plated connectors during humidity testing of the products. With gold plated connectors we did not encounter the problem. That's only a data point I can provide.

Comment: That is interesting. Btw, how did you conduct the humidity tests? Did you cycle between dry and humid air, and for how long time?

Comment: Would the person voting to close due to lack of detail please advise the nature of the details that they would consider useful.